# MS Access Adobe Acrobat Integration

Tags: ms-access, adobe

From within my Access app, I'm able to open, edit, save and close a PDF file using the Adobe Acrobat reference.  The app had been running great until recently.  Now, the "Save" command no longer works.  Is anyone aware of a patch, update, etc. from either Microsoft or Adobe that might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug in Acrobat version 2021.011.20039 which was auto-updated 1/12/22.  I rolled-back to my previous version and all is well.